# Java clone() in C#

Tags: java, c#, clone

I'm rewriting code from Java to C#.
I have a problem with clone function in C#.

Code in
**Java:**

```
public Tour(ArrayList tour)
{
    this.tour = (ArrayList) tour.clone();
}
```

My code in
**C#:**

```
public Tour(List<City> tour)
{
    //What I should do here?
}
```

I tried some techniques of cloning in C# but without results.

**EDIT:**

This solution works perfectly:

```
this.tour = new List<City>();
tour.ForEach((item) =>
{
     this.tour.Add(new City(item));
});
```

Greetings!

Comment: "I tried some techniques of cloning in C#..." - what exactly have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: The joke here is that C# also contains ArrayList which also contains Clone method which does the same thing as in Java.

Comment: @S_F But using `ArrayList` instead of generic `List<T>` mostly not so good idea.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Yes, but I found the situation funny.

Comment: This is a C# question to be sure, but nb.: it's _rarely_ a good idea to use the `Cloneable` / `.clone()` facility in Java.  Implement your own cloning mechanism (with whatever level of depth your spec requires), document it, and move on.  Java's clone was broken from day 1.  It's not a shallow vs. deep argument either; this facility is a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be implementing `ICloneable` on your `City` class.

That way you can do this:

```
public List<City> Tour {get; private set;}

public Tour(List<City> tour)
{
    this.Tour = new List<City>();
    foreach (var city in tour)
      this.tour.Add((City)city.Clone());    
}
```

Comment: However, that does not do what the Java code does. The Java code does a shallow copy of the ArrayList - the elements temselves are not copied. `new List<City>(tour)` would do in C#, and `new ArrayList(tour)` would be more common in Java than doing `tour.clone()`

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous then as "cloning" in Java obviously has a different meaning in C#. C# would be a deep copy, not a shallow copy.

Comment: Well, e.g. C# ArrayList.Clone does exactly the same thing as Java ArrayList.Clone - creates a shallow copy. A C# List has no .Clone method though.

Comment: Wouldn't the "MemberwiseClone" method suffice, then?

Comment: @nos: You can write an extension method for IList<T> which returns IEnumerable<T> and only accepts where T is ICloneable tho'. Easy-peasy. MemberwiseClone is also not safe in case of object references - better to implement a proper Clone() method.

Comment: I don't understand why `where T is ICloneable` would be required when OP wants a shallow copy of the list (to mimick Java functionality).

Answer (score 2):

> The `java.util.ArrayList.clone()` returns a shallow copy of this ArrayList instance (i.e the elements themselves are not copied).
>   <sub>--[Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_clone.htm)</sub>

To do the same thing in .NET's `List<T>` you can do:

```
var newList = oldList.ToList();
```